# Issue w/ play() function in manim

Tags: python, python-3.x, manim

I run this code:

```
from manimlib import *

class SquareToCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()
        self.play(ShowCreation(circle))
        self.play(circle.animate.shift(2 * RIGHT), circle.animate.scale(0.25))
```

It's shortened example from https://3b1b.github.io/manim/getting_started/quickstart.html. However, the circle doesn't shift right as specified with `circle.animate.shift(2 * RIGHT)` as seen [here](https://youtu.be/O-uGq0c3pNw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a correct way to do both animations at the same time

```
from manimlib import *

class SquareToCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()
        self.play(ShowCreation(circle))
        self.play(circle.animate.shift(2 * RIGHT).scale(0.25))
```

https://youtu.be/dwovjxTcvEk